# Initialize Map from Set

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, set, java-stream

I have a set of Student - `Set<Student> students`

```
class Student{
    String Id;
    String getId(){ return Id;} 
.....
}
```

I am trying to initialize a `Map<String,List<StudentResult>>` with the entries from set above:

```
Map<String,List<StudentResult>> studentResultMap = students.keySet().stream().collect(
                                                Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getId(),new ArrayList<StudentResult>()));
```

But this wouldn't compile - how is this to be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here lies your problem:

```
Map<String,List<StudentResult>> studentResultMap = students
    .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getId(), new ArrayList<StudentResult>()));
```

You need to pass two functions to `Collectors.toMap`, but instead, you're passing a `List` instance as the second parameter

```
Map<String,List<StudentResult>> studentResultMap = students
    .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getId(), x -> new ArrayList<StudentResult>()));
```

Answer (score 4):

`new ArrayList<StudentResult>()` does not make a correct argument for a `Function` parameter.

You need to use:

```
x -> new ArrayList<StudentResult>()
```

---

Side note: `students.keySet()` wouldn't compile either, if `students` is a `Set`. You can call `stream` on it directly:

```
students.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getId(), 
                                           a -> new ArrayList<>()));
```